# cannot convert from type void* (class name)(void*) to type void* (*)(void*) in a pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads, type-conversion

I am trying to create a thread in main function and call a function of another class through my thread.

In main.cpp:

```
SocketHandler *callserver;
pthread_t thread1;
pthread_create(&thread1,0, callserver->createSocket,NULL);
```

and in SocketHandler.h:

```
void* createSocket();
```

and in SocketHandler.cpp:

```
void * SocketHandler::createSocket()
{
    //....
}
```

When I am trying to compile main.cpp I am getting an error

> ```
>  cannot convert SocketHandler::createSocket from type void* (SocketHandler::)() to type void* ( * )(void*)
> ```

Comment: A non-static member function can't be used as a simple thread function. You need a static member function, or a non-member function. Oh, and of course whatever function you use, it needs to actually take a `void*` argument. Or you could of course go with the times and start using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: If you have C++11 or higher I would suggest you use the `std::thread` provided by the library so you do not have to muck about with `void*`s.

Comment: @NathanOliver or use `boost::thread` for pre C++11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pthread_create()` accepts only pointers to regular functions or class functions, not to member functions. And that pointer must be `void *(*)(void *)`. To workaround you can do next:

```
void *trampoline(void *arg) {
    SocketHandler *callServer = static_cast<SocketHandler *>(arg);
    callServer->createSocket();
    return nullptr;
}

// ...
SocketHandler *callserver;
pthread_t thread1;
pthread_create(&thread1,0, trampoline, callserver);
```

`trampoline()` may be inlined:

```
pthread_create(&thread1, 0, [](void* ptr){static_cast<SocketHandler*>(ptr)->createSocket(); return (void*)nullptr;}, callserver);
```

Alternatively you may use `std::thread`, that allows painless using of member functions too.

Comment: Folded it in: better inline than in comments.